# Accessing newly created Facebook Event returns false

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create Facebook events using its API as shown in the following code snippet.

```
function myCallback(callback_response) {
    var eventid = "";
    FB.api('me/events?access_token=(access_token)', 'POST', {name: "Test Event", start_time:1343143952067, privacy:"OPEN", location: "London, England"}, function(response){
        eventid = response.id;
        // eventid gets successfully return, 
        // however, accessing this eventid publicly returns 'false'

        FB.api('/'+ eventid+ '/invited?access_token=(access_token)&users='+callback_response.to,'POST',function(response) {
            // users successfully invited
        });
    });
}
```

The problem I am facing is that even though the event gets created and I get an eventid as a response, my second FB.api call to add users to the event fails. Also, on accessing the event directly (https://graph.facebook.com/(eventid)), facebook API returns false.

I have granted the create_event permission to the user so that should not be the problem. I am not sure why I am not able to see events created by own userid. Any suggestions?

Comment: You may have to delay your request for a while after you submit the event. It takes time sometimes for a new event to propagate through the FB server system.

Comment: Thanks cpilko, though I do not think that's the problem, as I get the same message even if I try to access the same event few minutes later.

Comment: Can you post a sample eventid?

Comment: Sure, here is one I created earlier - 449382708434971. As shown in the code, its privacy is set to OPEN.

Comment: I tried accessing http://www.facebook.com/events/449382708434971 unsuccessfully. This means that your event is *not* public, which might be a requirement with the *access_token* you are using.

Comment: Thanks Gil, though I have found out that it has nothing to do with access_token (I have provided it in the input). It has to do with the format of the start_time field. Added the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. In this particular case, it has nothing to do with access_token. The problem is with the format of start_time field.

Replacing (start_time:1343143952067) with something like (start_time:"2012-10-29T12:00:00") solves the problem.